# memset() behaving undesirably

Tags: memset

I am using memset function in C and having a problem. Here is my problem:

```
char* tail;
tail = //some memory address
int pbytes = 5;
```

When I call memset like:

```
**memset(tail+pbytes, 0 , 8); // It gives no error**
```

When I call memset like:

```
**memset(tail+pbytes, 0 , 9); // It goes into infinite loop**
```

When I call memset like:

```
**memset(tail+pbytes, 0 , 10); // last parameter (10 or above). It gives Segmentation fault**
```

What can be the reason of this? The program runs and gives output as desired but it gives segmentation fault in the end. I am using Linux 64 virtual machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

**OK. Let me clarify more with what i am doing. I am making 128 bytes (0-127 in array) data. I write 0(NULL) from byte 112 to 119 (it goes well) but when I try to write 0 on 120th byte and run the program, it goes into infinite loop. If I write 1,2,4,6 at 120th byte, program runs well. If I write other numbers at 120th byte, program gives segmentation fault. Basically there is something wrong with bytes from 120 to 127.**

Comment: where does '//some memory address' come from? has it been allocated with malloc?

Comment: Try to compile your code with `gcc -g -Wall` and to debug it with `gdb` (or perhaps also `valgrind`)

Comment: @ PeskyGnat Its memory address from the stack.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing wrong with `memset`. It's something wrong with how you defined your pointer variable `tail`.

If you simply wrote

```
    char tail[128];
    memset(tail+5, 0, 9);
```

of course it would work fine. Your problem is that you're not doing anything that simple and correct; you're doing something obscure and incorrect, such as

```
    char tail[1];
    memset(tail+5, 0, 9);
```

or

```
void foo(int x) {
    char *tail = &x;
    memset(tail+5, 0, 9);
}
```

To paraphrase Charles Babbage: When you put wrong code into the machine, wrong answers come out.

The segfault is probably because you're trying to write to a virtual address that has not yet been allocated. The infinite loop might be because you're overwriting some part of the memset's return address, so that it returns to the wrong place (such as into the middle of an infinite loop) instead of returning to the place it was called from.